# Is it possible to simulate ISP loader?

Tags: simulation, 8051, isp

If I want to make ISP loader for 89Sxxxx(8051),can I simulate it by multisim or others before I really build it?

I follow this link:

http://m955.com/wp/archives/142

I found it has a little hard to make it because multisim seems doesn't have printer port component to simulate.Am I right?

Thank you~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parallel port would not be the problem as it's just a connector - the difficult bit would be the uC and USB, and you would need to simulate the part being programmed.
It might be possible if Atmel have a simulation program for their chips (like MPLAB SIM for PICs) but even then I'm not sure it would cover all the peripherals fully (e.g. USB) and multiple chips.

It's a pretty simple/cheap circuit, so I would strongly suggest you just build it and debug as you go.

Comment: Thank you~I will try real circuit. I want to simulate because I am also interested in. Because I found that multisim 11 even can write main code on 8051 chip.I'm not really understand why this is difficult? And how this circuit related to uC(what is uC?) and USB?

Comment: uC = microcontroller. I initially thought the circuit used USB as I saw a USB connector in the photo. However on closer inspection this is just for power (data lines not connected) If Multisim can simulate an 8051 fully then it may be possible to use it. For a (non-commercial) project of this size, I still suggest just putting it together though, as it will probably be quicker to learn this way (plus you are using the "real thing"), and any mistakes will not be so costly.

Comment: I will make that circuit in real,thank for your advise. So back to the original question. It is possible to write code on multisim's 8051 chip,therefore I believe this component have full fuctionalities. But I can't find multisim have printer port component. Am I missing that or is there any other software can simulate printer port with 8051 chip?

Comment: @sam - I just tried to check on my MultiSim trial but unfortunately the time limit has expired :-) If you want to simulate communication with a PC and there is no "official" parallel port component, then I would look for something that can provide programmable stimulus to the required 8051 pins. IIRC there are a bunch of virtual instruments, so maybe one of these can do the job. I found a few simulators you might want to look at [here](http://avr.sourceforge.net/) and [here](http://www.amctools.com/atmel.htm). An 8051 based one [here](http://bit.kuas.edu.tw/~8051/)

Comment: Some more 8051 simulators on [this page](http://www.8052.com/links).

Comment: You say:'IIRC there are a bunch of virtual instruments'. What is IIRC?

Comment: I find it! Printer port is just on the components of DSUB*,such as DSUB25F in Multisim.